# Predicting moving median using incremental learning

Tags: machine-learning, median, moving-average

I would like to compute the moving median of a high velocity data streaming into a database. Unlike moving mean, however, there is no closed form equation for updating a moving median that does not require keeping track of all the previous data points.

I'm aware that moving median can be computed efficiently using [two heaps](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-stream-of-running-integers-using-stl/). But the issue is that I cannot rearrange the data inside the database because it is used by other downstream applications. So this approach would require me having two copies of the entire data: one in the database and another inside the two heaps.

So instead of the two heaps approach, I was thinking of using [incremental learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_learning) to predict the moving median every time a new data point arrives. I'll also scan the data  within the database once every few hours to compute the actual median so that I can incrementally train my model.

I'm wondering if this approach can work (or if there is any better alternative). Of course, the predicted value outputted by the model would be an approximate, but this is less of an issue for my application as long as it is pretty close to the actual value with high confidence every time.

Thank you.

Comment: If the data is high-velocity, why not just take the median of the last hundred or next hundred observations? A more formal statement of the constraints might help here.